# jQuery mobile button press event slow to process

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

It seems like whenever I press an input button or anchor button on a mobile device, it takes a second or two to process the onclick or press event.  Is there a way to speed this up?

I am using Phonegap + jQuery Mobile on an Android device, it seems to be a little faster on iOS

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Fast Buttons](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) will eliminate 300ms of the delay.

Answer (score 7):

From http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

> **$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay**
>
> If you find that the button down/hover state (lists, buttons, links etc) feels sluggish the $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay setting might be of use. It will decrease the time between the touch event and the application of the relevant class but will also result in a higher chance that the same class will be applied even when the user is scrolling (eg, over a long list of links).

For example:

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 500
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The touchend event is pretty snappy.

```
$(someElement).bind('touchend',function(){
  //other code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- jQuery mobile is a bit buggy and slow.
- Fast Buttons you need to
  control some behaviors by yourself.
- Fastclick messed up my code.
- **Tappy** is the solution in heavy-coded pages. It's lightweight and operative:

  [onClick event in android webview too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931102/onclick-event-in-android-webview-too-slow/24902600#24902600)