# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile = slow tap response time

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I know there are a lot of these questions on the internet, but I've tried every solution (all the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199989/jquery-mobile-button-press-event-slow-to-process)), and none of them worked.

When I run the site in my PC's browser everything's fine, but as soon as I deploy on the phone, the response time is very laggy.

I've tried using FastClick, setting hoverDelay to 0, and binding my own events, but the result is the same.

Am using Android 4.1. Would appreciate any help other than what I've tried.

Comment: For reference, here's a good JQM performance-tuning list: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/07/20/jquery-mobile-performance-improvement/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To speed up JQM, you have to turn off any transitions.

It sucks, but the JQM transitions are too slow for mobile devices, even on iOS. We'll just have to wait a few years until the hardware gets faster I suspect. This is despite the JQM team trying to improve the performance in 1.2. I still can't use the transitions without my apps feeling sluggish.

I always use these settings to get the best performance out of jQuery mobile.

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition   = 'none'
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none'
$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0
```

As well, if you are writing any javascript, **do not** bind to any 'click' events. Click is way too slow on mobile devices as it has an additional 300ms delay before the event is triggered.

Since you are using JQM, you can use their own click event `vclick` instead (which under the hood is using `touchstart` and `touchend` events).

If it's still really slow for you after that, you might have to examine what is actually happening in your click events - perhaps your code is not as optimised as it could be.

Comment: Do the transitions have anything to do with what happens before they actually fire up? Because the transition itself works flawlessly on my phone, it's the delay *before* the transition starts that bugs me. Also I don't really have any JS, except for a custom loading screen that does a `changePage` once Cordova & JQM are loaded and that's pretty much it. I will try disabling the transitions and come back with feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, sorry, no transitions whatsoever and still the lag. I've even tried changing the JQM core to replace the hoverDelay with 0, but still nothing.

Comment: @EduardLuca I would say at this point you need to work out if it is the content in your page which is causing the slowness. Sometimes if the DOM gets too big in a JQM app, it can appear slow. What does your page look like and which bit it taking too long?

Comment: I think you might be right. I have the entire content of about 5 pages in one file, and I use anchor links, so that might cause the issue. It just popped into my head that this isn't the only solution, there are AJAX links too :)

Comment: Sorry to be a party-pooper, but nothing works. I've set the `hoverDelay` to 0 and separated the HTML of the pages in separate files, but the delay is still there. I've decided to drop JQM because of all the bugs (this one and more) it has. Thanks for the assistance though!

Comment: I got here after seeing my app struggling in Android browsers. I disabled all animations, caching DOM lookups when possible, etc. Still slouch. I tested JQM demo page alone in several Android devices and overall they're slow, so definitely JQM out of the box is slow.

Comment: This solution rocks. Thank you so much for this solution.

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the discussion, but when you say to avoid binding to "click" events are you talking strictly jQuery click events or are you also including the inline "onclick" attribute?

Comment: @isick a jQuery click event "under the hood", is ultimately wrapping a native click event - which is the same as when you use an `onclick` attribute.  (which you should avoid BTW).   They both have the same 300 ms delay on mobile browsers.

jQuery Mobile's `vclick` however, uses touch events under the hood, so it doesn't suffer from that delay.

Comment: In the future though, mobile browsers will probably remove this 300 ms delay from click events.  Chrome is already making progress to do so: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away.  Might be a while before Mobile Safari joins suit though.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using the *tap* event than the click event if you want to work around this for a mobile application.

Have a read of [Tap vs. Click: Death by Ignorance](https://coderwall.com/p/bdxjzg) by [John Bender](https://coderwall.com/johnbender)

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet worked for me

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent, 
event = (ua.match(/iPad|Android/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$("button,a").bind(event, function()
{
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```