# Custom html / javascript keyboard too slow on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have created a simple numeric keypad running on phonegap for android and am using html / JavaScript to update an input box but the response is really slow. Wonder what is the reason. Simple code I am using is

```
if($('#checkout_wizard').is(":visible")) {
    txt = document.getElementById('txt_amount_paid');
} else {
    txt = document.getElementById('txt_number');
}

val = txt.value;

if( this.innerHTML!= '&lt;') {
    txt.value = val + this.innerHTML;
} else {
    txt.value = val.substring(0, val.length-1);
}
```

Anyway to speedup the virtual keybord?

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the virtual keyboard is extremely slow and the screen flickers when I switch from one input box to the other. This is especially when I use jQuery Mobile for the UI along with PhoneGap.

To optimize jQuery Mobile and speed up certain things, please [take a look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097351/phonegap-jquery-mobile-slow-tap-response-time)

Even if you are not using jQuery Mobile, an issue regarding the slow virtual keyboard has been mentioned here, please do take a look: http://floatlearning.com/2011/03/developing-better-phonegap-apps/

Comment: Hope that helped. Please do post here if you find any other findings that might help achieve it. That would be of great help.

Comment: If that link helped you resolve the problem, please do accept the answer :)