# How can I speed up jQueryMobile's turtle-slow buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

HTML5 and Javascript are fast.

Jquery Mobile is slow. My goal is not to use another library like bootstrap. My goal is to speed up an existing jquery mobile app.

Are there any css plugins / javascript trickery to easily speed up the buttons?

There is simply too much animation going on, is there a way to turn off the fancy button animation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13199989/1348195

Comment: Fast click https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick and use `vclick` instead of `tap` events.